# List all files in subfolder and search for file with same prefix name in R

Tags: r

list of subfolders and files within the subfolders

```
list.files(recursive = TRUE)
```

I used this code to get list of files from subfolder. It worked fine , but it is listing upto 1000 files and remaining files are ommited.

In a folder I have some subfolder(i.e. A,B,C,D) and in that subfolder I have further some folders(A - A1,A2,A3,... B - B1,B2,B3,....)

How to list all the files in subfolder?

From the list of output, I need to search the files which have same prefix name and list all that files in separate folder.

[image]

Comment: Do you know in advance the names of the subfolders from which you want to extract the filenames, or are you trying to find all the subfolders where, for example, files with prefix 359983006750511_ exist?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code does list all files, but as a default it only prints the first 1000. You could change this by setting options(max.print = 1000000) for example. However, if you assign the list.files() function to for example mylist <- as.list(list.files()) it will assign all 1000+ files anyway, without needing to adjust the max.print option. And if you want to select a certain pattern, you could add the pattern = "mypatternofinterest" argument in the list.files() function.